# Excel can't read XlsxWriter created formulas SUMIF

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create an Excel containing some formulas using the code:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('A1', 1)
worksheet.write('A2', 2)
worksheet.write('A3', 3)
worksheet.write('B1', '+')
worksheet.write('B2', '-')
worksheet.write('B3', '+')
formula = '=((SUMIF(B{f}:B{la},"+",{cl}{f}:{cl}{la})-'\
         + 'SUMIF(B{f}:B{la},"-",{cl}{f}:{cl}{la}))'\
         + '/MAX(SUMIF(B{f}:B{la},"/",{cl}{f}:{cl}{la}),1)'
print(formula.format(f=1, la=3, cl='A'))
# =((SUMIF(B1:B3,"+",A1:A3)-SUMIF(B1:B3,"-",A1:A3))/MAX(SUMIF(B1:B3,"/",A1:A3),1)

worksheet.write_formula('B5', formula.format(f=1, la=3, cl='A'))
workbook.close()
```

When opening this file using Microsoft Excel we see:

[Excel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO5Bw.png)

The cell containing `0` is the one with the formula.

When I use LibreOffice to open the same file I see the correct value.

Comment: Have you tried manually pasting this formula with the values in? What happens?

Comment: It works when I paste it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used two parenthesis, there should be only one in the start of your formula. it should be:

```
formula = '=(SUMIF(B{f}:B{la},"+",{cl}{f}:{cl}{la})-'\
         + 'SUMIF(B{f}:B{la},"-",{cl}{f}:{cl}{la}))'\
         + '/MAX(SUMIF(B{f}:B{la},"/",{cl}{f}:{cl}{la}),1)'
```